# Web Browser Control - Scroll with content

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a Jquery website which is a terminal. It works great, and I would like to mount it within a windows form using the WebBrowser control. However I would need the focus of the control to scroll as new content is loaded.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".